# Typeface.createFromAsset() returning null pointer exception for font

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

In my login activity for my app, I'm assigning a variable to a font in my assets folder. However, when I run the app, I get a stacktrace in the logcat saying that the method is returning a null pointer exception.

Here's my `LoginActivity.java`

```
package com.joshhess.fittrak;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // UI Elements
    @BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        // Set font for widgets
        Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(roboto);
    }
}
```

Here's my stacktrace:

```
    06-21 13:37:37.298 27151-27151/com.joshhess.fittrak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.joshhess.fittrak, PID: 27151
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joshhess.fittrak/com.joshhess.fittrak.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.joshhess.fittrak.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:24)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

And finally, here's my `activity_login.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.joshhess.fittrak.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Does anyone have any idea why its returning a null reference? My folder is called assets and the file name is correct.

Comment: don post the source code as screenshots...

Comment: The problem isn't your Typeface. The problem is because the @BindView isn't working and title is null.

Comment: It seems your TextView is not assigned proper view. Kindly share your java code.

Comment: Also share your `activity_login.xml` code.

Comment: your `TextView` is null and therefore you cannot set the typeface to it

Comment: See this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/285 and also make sure your `build.gradle` files have these: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Renan Bandeira, I realized my problem. My `build.gradle` file did not include `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'`. After I added that line under the compile line, it worked perfectly fine. Here are my dependencies now in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer in 2 days, thank you to Renan Bandeira again for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The field *title* is still null.
so when you called

`title.setTypeFace(robot)`

then it will be nullPointerException because you are calling a method on null object.
I think

```
@BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;
```

the title is not initialized.
Please debug it, for the title value, you will get the exact problem that what is null. May be there is problem in ButterKnife configuration.

I found below similar question, may be it can help you to debug and fix it.
[How to debug Null Pointer Exception raised by Butterknife in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004718/null-pointer-exception-issues-with-butterknife-android-application-developme)